# How to override save() method of modelform class and added missing information?

Tags: python, django, save, models, modelform

I just started to learn Django and I had a question.

I'm trying to automatically add the missing information, when saving form data. I get to change/add the desired "cleaned_data" information by overriding save() method of modelform class, but changes are not recorded in the database. Actually, how to write the modified information? This is code:

```
def save(self, commit = True, *args, **kwargs):
    temp = ServiceMethods(url = self.cleaned_data.get('url'), wsdl_url = self.cleaned_data.get('wsdl_url'))

    if not temp.get_wsdl_url():                             
        temp.make_wsdl_url()

    if temp.get_wsdl_url():                                 
        temp.make_wsdl()                                    
        self.cleaned_data['wsdl_url'] = temp.get_wsdl_url() 
        self.cleaned_data['wsdl_description'] = temp.get_wsdl_description()

    super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit = commit, *args, **kwargs)
```

And model:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=256)
    url                 = models.URLField('Ссылка', unique = True)
    wsdl_url            = models.URLField('Ссылка на WSDL-документ', blank=True)
    description         = models.TextField('Описание сервиса',blank=True)
    wsdl_description    = models.TextField('WSDL описание', blank=True, editable=False)
    added               = models.DateTimeField('Добавлено', auto_now_add=True)
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the data on `self.instance` instead of in `self.cleaned_data`, and let me know if that works.